# First Attempt at Object Oriented VBA fails

Tags: excel, vba

Question: Why do I get nothing but 0 out of this code? (via the MsgBox)

Context: Newbie trying to learn to use my own classes in Excel VBA.

Class1 is a class Module which has the code here:

```
 Private pPhone As Integer

 Public Property Get Phone() As Integer
 Phone = pPhone
 End Property

 Public Property Let Phone(Value As Integer)
 pPhone = Phone
 End Property
```

And Test() is a sub in Module1 as you see here

```
Dim Home As Class1

Public Sub Test()
Set Home = New Class1
Home.Phone = 3
MsgBox Home.Phone
End Sub
```

The code executes, but Home.Phone is only reported as 0 (I guess the initial value) What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `pPhone = Phone` to `pPhone = Value`

It should be

```
 Public Property Let Phone(Value As Integer)
 pPhone = Value
 End Property
```